# In Julia, are there cpu/memory dissadvantages when functions that modify their arguments return nothing?

Tags: function, julia

I have a general question about how to declare functions in Julia. If my new function modifies one of its parameters, should it return:
a. the modified parameter?
or
b. nothing?

I mean, if the function modifies its argument, I will see the modifications in the respective object even if the function does not return it.
What would be the dissadvantages/advantages or returning/not returning the modified parameter.

An example here:

```
julia> a= [2,3,5]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3
 5

#Variant 1, the function returns its modified argument
julia> function addA!(a)
       a .= a .+ 5
       return a
       end
addA! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> addA!(a)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  7
  8
 10

#Variant 2, the function returns nothing
function addA!(a)
a .= a .+ 5
       return nothing
       end
addA!

addA!(a)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't matter for performance. It's just a matter of convenience or style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first variant is used extensively in the Julia standard libraries, so this style is preferred in general. For instance see `push!`, `map!`, `rand!`, `mul!`, etc. This style fits with Julia's "everything is an expression" philosophy, and is convenient because functions can often be substituted with their in-place versions without any other changes: e.g.  `sort(filter(isodd, A))` => `sort!(filter!(isodd, A))`. It also makes implementing the allocating version of an in-place function easy:

```
foo(A) = foo!(copy(A)) # common idiom in the stdlib
```

There's no disadvantage in terms of performance.